# Broadcom BCM4331 not working on new Mac Mini 5,1

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom, mac-mini

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Broadcom BCM4331: “device not ready firmware missing” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183192/broadcom-bcm4331-device-not-ready-firmware-missing-error)

I can't seem to get my wireless card working on my Mac Mini 5,1. Lspci returns:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 02)
```

But running "additional drivers" doesn't detect anything. The nm-applet menu reads "device not ready--firmware missing." What can I do to get this to work?

Note, this is with 12.04.1, so many of the previous discussions (for 11.10, etc) probably don't apply here.

Comment: Try `sudo modprobe -r brcmsmac && sudo modprobe b43`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by following the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro8-2#Wireless, namely:

> There is no official support yet in Ubuntu 12.04, but you can get it
>   working with the following repository.
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpodroid/mactel
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
> ```
>
> For Precise, the Compat module should also be installed
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.3-precise-generic
> ```
>
> Edit the /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and add the line:
>
> ```
> blacklist ndiswrapper
> ```
>
> Create or edit the file /etc/pm/config.d/modules and make sure the
>   wireless modules (b43 and bcma) are blacklisted:
>
> ```
> SUSPEND_MODULES="b43 bcma"
> ```
>
> Reboot and the wireless should work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem in a Acer Extensa 5620Z with 12.04 LTS installed and finally I have found the solution in this forum (in Spanish): [[Solución] Problemas con el wifi Broadcom BCM4311](http://www.portalubuntu.com/2011/11/solucion-problemas-con-el-wifi-broadcom.html).

Here I translate the conclusion:

> The solution is to uninstall the driver and install a package that
> downloads and installs a driver that works correctly:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

And restart the computer to load drivers at startup.

I hope that it works on your computer.