# Intel® Centrino® Wireless-N 1000 - Wifi connection is very slow - how do I configure or fix it?

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, iwlwifi, centrino

I'm a new Ubuntu user trying to get my wifi working properly.

How do I install a downloaded driver?

After changing some configurations in my router I'm able to get 5Mbps on my laptop (but +100Mbps on my smartphone)

I've also followed [this whole itsfoss tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/) but I'm still not getting the full speed.

Recently I've found [the proper driver on intel.com](https://www.intel.com.br/content/www/br/pt/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html).

I've copied the `iwlwifi-1000-3.ucode` file to `/libfirmware`

But I guess my wifi is still using the generic driver.

```
$ lshw -C network

  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:26:c7:b2:b3:18
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-29-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 ip=192.168.1.36 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
$ lsb_release -a
$ hostnamectl

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
root@roberto-HP-Pavilion-dm4-Notebook-PC:/home/roberto# hostnamectl
   Static hostname: roberto-HP-Pavilion-dm4-Notebook-PC
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
        Machine ID: 4261b4ee39b7492d88bca690bdbcb8eb
           Boot ID: 999a755c19264f008eb441c6607ab432
  Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-29-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] [8086:0084]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN [8086:1315]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Are you using a USB dongle or a built-in PCI device? Why do you thiing you have an Intel device? There is absolutely no information about your device in your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Did you try using `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` yet?

Comment: Sorry, guys. My mistake. I'll update with ```lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list```. And the right part of ```lshw -C network```

Comment: @iggy12345, following results: ```~$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
No drivers found for installation.```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, guys! My mistake.

By executing: `$ nmcli dev wifi list`

### 1. I've realized it was a router configuration.

It was only 802.11b (limited to 11mbps).

I've changed to 802.11n (up to 130mbps).

### 2. I've also realized that

There is a bug on [Intel Support for Linux Page](https://www.intel.com.br/content/www/br/pt/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html). The Intel® Centrino® Wireless-N 1000 firmware versions are switched between Kernel versions 3.2+ and 2.6.30+.

Then [I've followed this steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350474/intel-centrino-wireless-n-1000-again-ubuntu-13-04-x64):

```
$ tar -xvzf iwlwifi-1000-ucode-39.31.5.1.tgz 
$ cd iwlwifi-1000-ucode-39.31.5.1/
$ sudo cp iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode /lib/firmware/
```