# Need help with making my wifi work on my HP - DV6 - 2155dx

Tags: drivers, 20.04, iwlwifi

I am a total beginner with linux and I'm having a hard time making my wifi work :(

upon reading forums, it said enter some commands in the terminal and I got this:

```
'''02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]

DeviceName: Intel(R) Wi-Fi Link 1000

Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN

Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29

Memory at d5400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) \[size=8K\]

Capabilities: <access denied>

Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

Kernel modules: iwlwifi'''
```

from there I don't know where to go or what to do.

I even don't know how to install packages via terminal.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu.  Are you able to connect to a wireless router at all?  Is it just a little slow and perhaps undependable?

Comment: Yup. I am connected to the same network with my phone and other pc. also before formatting this laptop - I was able to connect to wifi through win7

Comment: There are some other posts in AskUbuntu which indicate that you may have the wrong version of the wireless adaptor drivers.  I can type up a lengthy sort of an answer to change the drivers, with I hope enough detail that you will be comfortable using the terminal window.  It will take me a couple of minutes.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

There is a small confusion at the [Intel wireless support](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html) page, and you may have the wrong driver for your system.

To resolve this, you will need to download the correct driver form Intel, unpack the compressed files, and copy one specific file to a system directory, and then reboot your computer.

First, open a terminal - press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>

Now we will make a folder that we can do the work in, and change to that directory.  To do this, enter the following commands.

```
mkdir wifistuff
cd wifistuff
```

Now download the correct driver:

```
wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-1000-ucode-39.31.5.1.tgz
```

And uncompress the files

```
tar -xvzf iwlwifi-1000-ucode-39.31.5.1.tgz
```

Handy hit here:  Type `tar -xvzf iwl` and then press <kbd>tab</kbd>

Not change to a directory that was created by the uncompression:

```
cd iwlwifi-1000-ucode-39.31.5.1
```

Copy the microcode to the correct system directory.  First, make a backup of the file that is already there.

```
sudo cp /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode{,.bak}
sudo cp iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode /lib/firmware/
```

Please note that the `sudo` part of this command will prompt you to enter your password.

Finally

```
reboot
```

---

I have largely cribbed this answer from [Intel® Centrino® Wireless-N 1000 - Wifi connection is very slow - how do I configure or fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238656/intel-centrino-wireless-n-1000-wifi-connection-is-very-slow-how-do-i-confi)