# Lubuntu 20.04 - Wifi doesn't work / newbie question

Tags: wireless, 20.04

Sorry for this request:

Using Lubuntu 20.04, I cannot get my wifi to work. (Already before switching to Linux, it was mostly not working, with some exceptions. I assume, I simply don't have the current driver anymore...)

Unfortunately, I still miss the basics of using Linux / Lubuntu. As I don't have internet right now, I can't look them up and read manuals as I had intended to learn the basics: I have moved, though, and my internet provider doesn't manage to get my LAN to work in my new home... well, and I don't manage to get wifi working. So I don't know how to fix this mess because I only get to use internet at a friend's house right now, for short intervals (not enough to really enter the Linux world).

So if anyone would be so incredibly kind to point me to something to read for complete Linux newbies (I didn't even manage to find the right "settings"!) to install the driver to get the wifi going (sort of a silly step-by-step thing for new-comers), that'd be just incredibly awesome...

(And I fully understand if some of you don't want to be bothered with this kind of question--just please ignore it then. Sorry!)

Thanks a million for any help!

Comment: This will depend quite a bit on what WiFi adapter your computer has; you should probably state that in your question. But the first thing to try is to connect your computer to a wired connection and then go to Preferences > Additional Drivers in the main menu. That app will show you what hardware you have that needs a special driver. If your wireless adapter is listed, you can then choose the proprietary driver and click "Apply".

Comment: Does only the WiFI you want to connect to not show up, or are there no networks shown (ex. your neighbors WiFI), or does it let you connect but you have "No Internet Access" (or similar)?

Comment: FYI:  Being specific as you can be is sometimes helpful, Lubuintu 20.04? 20.04.1? or 20.04.2?  (20.04 & 20.04.1 use the GA or 5.4 kernel, 20.04.2 uses HWE thus 5.8 kernel).  You can obtain details of your hardware via `sudo lshw -C network` (list-hardware of class network) which will provide details of your chipset which controls wifi which is key to solving it (on windows it's brand/model which then tells you chipset.. Linux skips the brand/model going straight to chipset of device). Once you have chipset you can usually easily resolve the issue using online searches.

Comment: See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Devices

Comment: if it is opening some websites and some not, reduce mtu value  for the wifi network (suggested 1452) in ipv4 tab

Comment: @HarryCutts: There is no entry in Preferences > Additional Drivers: "No additional drivers available". / "No proprietary drivers are in use."

Comment: @jitter: I don't have functioning wifi, so I do not get any networks displayed. Unfortunately, I don't even know yet where (!) they would be displayed... - ?

Comment: @Guiverc: I didn't succeed with your first comment [the command line initially says "a@a-2842fbu:~$ " ... I simply typed "sudo lshw -C network" and pressed the "enter" key... and received a new line with "[sudo] password for a: ▮" ... after that, the command line didn't let me enter anything?...] ... so I used the link (thanks!). I know now my wireless device again (Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1000) and continued to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Drivers ...

Comment: ... where I got stuck again under 2.1: "Check in System > Administration > Hardware Drivers for a binary driver." - sorry for the silly question, but how do I get there? Looks to me like it should be in some menu, but I don't find where? ... - Alternately, I found this website incl. my wireless driver: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html ... How do I find out if my kernel falls under "3.2+" or "2.6.30+"?  ... Thanks so much already!!!

Comment: @Oppili: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll keep it in mind... but I don't have a wifi connection at all, and even if I did, wouldn't know yet how / where to reduce the mtu value or the tab you mention... where would that be?

Comment: copy this command in qterminal  nmcli d wifi list
it will show available wifi networks,

Comment: to connect to wifi type following  nmcli dev wifi con "WifiName" password "WifiPassword"     in qterminal . nmtui in qterminal also helps. Right bottom wifi signal bar will also give wifi lists.

Comment: @Oppili: When I copied " nmcli d wifi list" to the command line, I received "IN-USE  BSSID  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY". Not sure what that means... :-/ ... I don't seem to have a "right bottom wifi signal bar". (I suppose it should be next to the icons for battery status, sound, LAN / ethernet connection etc.?) Again, I'm pretty sure that I'm missing a driver, at least I have not yet installed one...

Comment: @Guiverc: PS: I tried to download & unpack both Intel drivers while waiting to hear which one to use. I understand I would have to unpack by entering "tar zxvf" into the prompt to unpack tgz files. But the prompt returns: "tar zxvf iwlwifi-1000-ucode-39.31.5.1.tgz
tar (child): iwlwifi-1000-ucode-39.31.5.1.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or d
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now" ... not sure how to unpack instead? (BTW, my Windows mind asks: Shouldn't I indicate the path to the files in some way?)

Comment: @Guiverc: Well, I managed to unpack what I even consider to be the correct driver...  but it appears I should have firmware loader support enabled, but I cannot find the indicated path/ right place. If you should have another magic link, that'd be incredibly awesome... Again sooo sorry for my complete ignorance and lack of online time to just look things up by myself (and just google my way in an hour or two...)... sorry!!!!!!

Comment: Additional detail should be added to your question (greater formatting is possible there making it easier to read).  Lubuntu 20.04 LTS is available with two software stacks (GA or 5.4 kernel) & HWE (sorry I forget what that is currently, 5.8 or 5.11; I'll look later) so I'd have opted to switch stacks first (*drivers* are officially kernel modules, thus the importance of kernel in use; the stack chosen by what ISO you install with though it can be switched post-install assuming you've internet connection to download other stack choice). I'll post a possible answer via *duplicate* link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intel® Centrino® Wireless-N 1000 - Wifi connection is very slow - how do I configure or fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238656/intel-centrino-wireless-n-1000-wifi-connection-is-very-slow-how-do-i-confi)

Comment: There is no need to apolgize... we all start somewhere/sometime..

Comment: @Guiverc: Thanks a lot for your patience! I'm just sorry because I cannot just work my way through online manuals as I naturally would (and wanted to), given my internet problems... so I'm asking question from forum members like you that I could have ordinarily easily have solved by myself... Anyways, I really have 0 wireless access on my computer, so it's not just slow. (I only have access when I visit someone where I plug a LAN cable.) Unfortunately, I don't remember which exact Lubuntu 20.04 version I installed--where can I look it up? And what is a stack?